# Latex compilation error submitting to Bioinformatics journal

Tags: errors, journal-publishing

I'm trying to submit a paper to the Bioinformatics journal that uses manuscriptcentral. The problem resides in their logo, OUP_First_SBk_Bot_8401.eps. I uploaded it with all the possible designations, however, it is not found by the compiler.

As it can be seen the file is uploaded: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBFOy.png

The image is loaded inside the style file: bioinfo.cls. This is the error that appears in the main.log:

```
LaTeX Warning: File `OUP_First_SBk_Bot_8401.eps' not found on input line 38.

! LaTeX Error: File `OUP_First_SBk_Bot_8401.eps' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.38 \maketitle
               
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in OUP_First_SBk_Bot_8401.eps (
no BoundingBox).
```

I'm stuck here. Any help will be apreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about your document setup. Where did you obtain `OUP_First_SBk_Bot_8401.eps` and `bioinfo.cls`? Were there other files that had to be uploaded?

Comment: They are found inside the template provided by them. [link](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/pages/submission_online) I uploaded all the files requested when adding the main document. Basically, the main.tex, bioinfo.cls, natbib.bst, my bib and my figures. The OUP_First_SBk_Bot_8401.eps is not requested but is needed by the cls.

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you solve it?

Comment: I also encountered the same problem. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by added the following lines to my main tex-file:

```
% Workaround to make 'manuscriptcentral' recognizing the Bioinformatics logo eps-file
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\include{OUP_First_SBk_Bot_8401.eps}
\endgroup
```

The "include" seems to make the file know, i.e. a requirement, for the compiling sandbox (?). The remain code is just to prevent insertion of additional spaces into the document. After added those lines I could upload the source files to manuscriptcentral and they compiled to the proper PDF.